# Self signed certificate not working fine in Android 7.1 browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have a self signed certificate and it's working fine upto Android 6. But not working fine in Android 7.0 and up.

I am aware on that Android 7.0 changed the certificate trust function.. now self signed certificate install into user path and chrome browser fail to trust my certificate. So could you please let me know there is any quick fix for this.